# How do I display rows of data from mysql database onto a pdf document using fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I have attempted to fetch information from MYSQL DATABASE to be displayed on a pdf document but only the Logo and the Title appear on the PDF Document that I h have generated. No data from the DB is displayed.

Kindly help
Below is the code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','branch','branch2012');
mysqli_select_db($con,"branch");

$sql="SELECT FirstName, PostalAddress, LastName, MobileNo FROM Patients WHERE Id = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($rows= (mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)))
{           
    $name = $rows['FirstName'];
    $address = $rows['PostalAddress'];
    $class = $rows['LastName'];
    $phone = $rows['MobileNo'];

    $pdf->SetXY (20,60);
    $pdf->SetFontSize(12);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
    $pdf->Write(7,$name);
    $pdf->SetXY (20,65);
    $pdf->Write(7,$address);
    $pdf->SetXY (20,70);
    $pdf->Write(7,$class);
    $pdf->SetXY (20,90);
    $pdf->Write(7,$phone);
    $pdf->Ln(); 
}

//Output the document
$pdf->Output('test.pdf','I');
```

Comment: Turn on all error reporting so you will see any errors that might be happening. `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: From your description of the problem your query is not working as you expect it to and there are no results to go through.

Comment: I just need the data from the database to be displayed on the pdf document.

Comment: Step 1) Verify that data are returned from the database and are accessible the way you think? => print_r Step 2) Try to apply the output to the PDF. Just divide your task´s in sub-task and proceed step-by-step.

Comment: Practical example?